# ElasticSearch Grails plugin

Tags: grails, elasticsearch-plugin

it is my first time to use [elasticsearch Grails plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) in my `Grails2.5.1`application , when i'm trying to search for `age=35` using `elasticSearchService.search("${age:35}").searchResults` or using `domainName.search("${age:35}").searchResults` the `searchresults` is empty although there is a record in the DB age is equal to `35`. And is there any useful tutorial for using `ElasticSearch` with Grails.

here is my domain:

```
class EmploymentSeeker {
String empType
String email
String fullName
 String expYears
 String socialStatus
  Integer  nubOfKids =0
   String computerKnowledge
  String militaryStatus
  String haveDrivingLic
 String gender
 String eduQualification
 String hasVehicle
 String placeOfStudying
 String courses
 String currentTitle
 String currentEmployerName
 Integer age
 Date dateCreated


static searchable = {
age boost:2.0
root true
except = ['email', 'fullName', 'placeOfStudying', 'currentTitle', 'currentEmployerName', 'dateCreated']
}

 static constraints = {

}
static mapping={

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a rogue '$' in your query string. It probably should be:

elasticSearchService.search("age:35")

${..} is needed only if you are passing in a query and want Groovy to replace the expression before invoking the ElasticSearchService.

Comment: i did it as you mentioned but still the same result .

Comment: Well then without much information hard to say what's wrong. Are you sure the data is getting indexed? I personally have not used the Grails plugin - we rolled out our own client based on Elasticsearch java api, mainly due to lack of documentation you mentioned. However you should be able to query elasticsearch directly to see if the objects are getting indexed. https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head would help in that respect.

Comment: what kind of data needed  to figure out what is wrong ?